# if imagesNamesList==["None" for x in range(len(listOfImages)]:

Tags: python

I am getting a syntax error at the line

`if imagesNamesList==["None" for x in range(len(listOfImages)]:`

I am not sure what I have done wrong...can someone point it out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis:

```
if imagesNamesList==["None" for x in range(len(listOfImages))]:
#                                                     here--^
```

However, you could write this code better (cleaner and more efficiently) like so:

```
if imagesNamesList == ["None"]*len(listOfImages):
```

---

Or, if your lists are huge, you can do as @mgilson noted:

```
if all(x == "None" for x in imagesNamesList) and len(imagesNamesList) == len(listOfImages):
```

Though this method requires more syntax, it is actually more efficient because of the short-circuiting property of [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all) (it will stop evaluating at the first `x == "None"` that comes back `False`, if any).

Comment: How about `if all(x == 'None' for x in imagesNamesList) and (len(imagesNamesList) == len(listOfImages)): ...`

Comment: @mgilson - I like that.  On smaller lists, the difference in efficiency is negligible but with large ones, it should be a lot more efficient.